# React + Axios: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Trying to go through a simple Axios tutorial to start getting used to populating dynamic data. [Loading and Using External Data in React](http://mediatemple.net/blog/tips/loading-and-using-external-data-in-react/)

I had to create a JSON web server since hitting Codepen with localhost violated CORS.

**App.jsx**

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return{
      users: []
    };
  },  
  componentDidMount: function(){
    var _this = this;
    this.serverRequest =
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:3004/users")
        .then(function(results){
          console.log(results.data);
          _this.setState({
            users: results.data.users
          });
         });
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function(){
    //...
  },
  render: function(){
    return(
        <div>
          <h3>Returning Users:</h3>
            {this.state.users.map(function(user) {
          return (
            <div>{user.name}</div>
          );
         })}
        </div>
    );
  }
});

export default App;
```

I understand that data should be extrapolated out into something like Redux but this is just a start to working with dynamic data. The error I'm getting is `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` I can't find very good explanations of this error doing some research. So what am I doing wrong?

I see that if I pre-populate data into the `getInitialState` I can get a return. So what is going wrong with the Promise getting data loaded into the initial state?

### Edits:

**Console.log Image:**

[image]

Comment: What is the result of this line  `console.log(results.data);`

Comment: I get a data return as expected. It looks like that data isn't being pushed into the user array in `getInitialState`

Comment: can you show the output of  `console.log(results.data);` ?

Comment: I've added an image for the console output

Comment: is this the output of `results.data` or `results.data.users` ??

Comment: Just made the change that was the problem, thank you for making me take another look at that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the result of your console output. It doesn't contain the `key users' and hence

```
 _this.setState({
        users: results.data.users
      });
```

will set the state users to undefined and hence you get an `error when trying to use map`

Change the setState to

```
 _this.setState({
        users: results.data
      });
```

Comment: I am really happy to write a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586810/react-axios-uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-cannot-read-property-map-of-un#comment72305843_42586810) useful to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its because the user state is empty initially, willmount method did nothing here,so it directly goes to render method and then goes to didmount, in render method it tries to map the user state with undefined value, that causes the error, i think you should check the user state is undefined or not. check it directly in render method or create a function for rendering the mapping. (suppose the method name is renderUser), then you can put the method fetching directly as {this.renderUser()}

Change your setState to this,

```
_this.setState({
    users: results.data
});
```